# MVC Route with Web-API (404 Error)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-web-api

I've having a heck of a time figuring out why my routing configuration isn't work. I tried mysite/issues/500 and mysite/issues/ but i always get a 404 error. I put a breakpoint in both the get functions and it never hits the breakpoint. Thought maybe glimpse could help me but i tried to

Here is my global.asax:

```
    Public Class MvcApplication
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

    Sub Application_Start()
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()
        RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute("Issues", "{controller}/{id}", New With {.id = UrlParameter.Optional})
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Controller:

```
Namespace Controllers


    Public Class IssuesController
        Inherits ApiController

        ' GET api/issues'
        Public Function GetValues(ByVal req As HttpRequestmessage) As IEnumerable(Of Issue)
            Dim querystrParams As NameValueCollection = Nothing
            Dim srch As IQuery
            If req.RequestUri.Query.Any() Then
                srch = New IssueTrackerQuery(req.RequestUri.ParseQueryString())
            End If
            Return (New EnumerableQuery(Of Issue)(New HashSet(Of Issue)))
        End Function

        ' GET api/issues/5'
        Public Function GetValue(ByVal IssuesId As Integer) As Issue
            Return New Issue()
        End Function

        ' POST api/issues'
        Public Sub PostValue(ByVal value As String)
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Sub

        ' PUT api/issues/5'
        Public Sub PutValue(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal value As String)
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Sub

        ' DELETE api/issues/5'
        Public Sub DeleteValue(ByVal IssuesId As Integer)
            Throw New NotImplementedException()
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have any API routes in your Global.asax. Add one using the `MapHttpRoute` extension method (instead of `MapRoute`):

```
Sub Application_Start()
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Issues", "{controller}/{id}", New With {.id = UrlParameter.Optional})
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters)
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
End Sub
```

Notice the `routes.MapHttpRoute` which registers the web api controllers.

Comment: Thank you very much Darin. That was it! I knew it had to be something small but i didn't notice using the wrong route function :).

Comment: I also noticed MS puts in routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", and I wasn't including "api/" in my url when testing. Reading this pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!